# Increment a value when JButton Is Pressed

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, jbutton

I've been trying to learn java for about a week now yet I've been stuck with one bug.  This is supposed to increment the variable "clicks" by 1 every time the button is pressed but I keep getting the same error:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Testclass {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton button1;
    private JLabel label;


    public Testclass () {

        gui();

    }

    public void gui () { 

        final int clicks = 0;

        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.cyan);

        button1 = new JButton("Test");
        label = new JLabel("Button Click Count: ");

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                clicks++;
                label.setText("Click Count: " +clicks);

            }


        });

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button1);

        frame.add(panel);



    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        new Testclass();


    }

}
```

It keeps giving me an error on line 42, where "clicks" is incremented "Multiple Markers at this line"
any help is appreciated. thanks, jack

Comment: *"It keeps giving me an error on line 42.."*  Douglas Adams was ***right!***

Answer (score 3):

```
  final int clicks = 0;
```

make   `clicks`  as a instance member. Nowit is final you cannot increment it.

If you remove final in the current place you cannot access inside the `actionPerformed`, So make it as instance member.

```
public class Testclass {

   private int clicks = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `clicks` as instance variable, because of you can't change `final` variable.

Read more about [varibles in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) and [final modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29).

Answer (score 1):

`final` is a declaration to say that the variable is a constant.

You must remove `final` and set `public` or `private`. By default, if you don't set anything, it will be `private`. Further, you must to declare it like a member of the class.

By default, eclipse suggests you to declare the variable as `final` but many times that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
final int clicks = 0
```

Final varaible value can not be change so make your varaible as `public` or `private`
its depend upon your need

```
private int clicks =0
```